# CSS Menu to display vertically with sub menus to the right

Tags: html, css

I am using this CSS Code:

```
.vertical-nav {
    height:auto;
    list-style:none;
    width: 100%; /******* MODIFIED ********/
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
.vertical-nav li {
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background-color: #666;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;  /******* MODIFIED ********/
}
.vertical-nav li:hover {
    background-color:#f36f25;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.vertical-nav li a {
    font-family:Calibri, Arial;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.vertical-nav li.current {
    background-color:#F36F25;
}
.vertical-nav li.current a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul {
    display:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:125px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-left:-5px;
}
vertical-nav ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
vertical-nav ul li:hover ul li {
    background-color:#555555;
    width:125px;
    height:30px;
    display:inline-block;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li:hover {
    background-color:#333333;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li a {
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
vertical-nav ul li ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.vertical-nav li ul {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
.vertical-nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
.vertical-nav li:hover .sub-menu
{
    display: table;
}
.sub-menu li
{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 180px;
    white-space: nowrap;  
    display:table-row;
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
}
.sub-menu li a
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

For my horizontal menu, How can I make the menu display vertically but also have the sub menus display out to the right of each link on hover?

Please check Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QdDmL/)

Comment: Your code seems to have a lot of redundant stuff, such as two `display` declarations on the `...li:hover ul` element. It might pay to fix these up sometime.

Answer (score 7):

Try the code in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/QdDmL/5/

I Changed:

```
.vertical-nav li:hover .sub-menu
{
position: relative;   
margin-top: -27px;
}

.sub-menu li
{
position: relative;
display: block;
top: 0;
left: 100%;
width: 100%;
min-width: 180px;
white-space: nowrap;
z-index:1;
}
```

this makes the submenu float to right of the menu. Making the position relative is a crucial part. With the margin-top it is aligned to the correct menu item.

Cheers

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why using -27.5px? I don't know one monitor that can display a half pixel. I can't imagine how this should by physically possible :P

Comment: sorry :D just -27px then

Answer (score 4):

Use the following:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="vertical-nav">
    <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li><br/>
    <li class="second"><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a herf="">Sub Link 1</a></li><br/>
    <li><a href="">Sub Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.vertical-nav{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.vertical-nav li{
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.vertical-nav li a{
    background-color: #666;
    padding:15px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Calibri, Arial;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.vertical-nav ul{
    padding:1px;
    display:none;
}

.vertical-nav li:hover a{
    background-color:#f36f25;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

.vertical-nav .second:hover ~ .sub-menu{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QdDmL/9/)

Comment: I can't seem to hover over the submenu?

Comment: @FilipHuysmans I just created the fiddle for what the user asked : **CSS Menu to display vertically with sub menus to the right**

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to create vertical menu with any deep using single universal style class for each level:

https://jsfiddle.net/k8gy79tv/1/

**CSS:**

```
nav ul {list-style-type: none; margin:0; padding:0; width: 200px; background-color: #f1f1f1; position: fixed;}
nav ul li {min-width: 200px; font-size:14px;}
nav ul li a {display: block; color: #000; text-decoration: none; padding: 16px 0 16px 16px;}
ul li:hover > a {color: white; background-color: #555;}

.dropdown-content {
    min-width: 150px;
    display: none;
    left: 200px;
    float:left;
    position: absolute;
    font-size:14px;
    margin-top: -48px;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 16px 0 16px 16px;
}
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-content {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<nav>
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu item 1</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu item 11</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-content">
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu item 111</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-content">
                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu item 1111</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-content">
                                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu item 11111</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="">Menu item 11112</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="">Menu item 11113</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="">Menu item 11114</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Menu item 1112</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Menu item 112</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Menu item 113</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Menu item 12</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Menu item 13</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Menu item 14</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  <li><a href="">Menu item 2</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu item 3</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-content">
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu item 31</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu item 311</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-content">
                    <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Menu item 3111</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-content">
                            <li><a href="">Menu item 31111</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Menu item 31112</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Menu item 31113</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Menu item 31114</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Menu item 312</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Menu item 313</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Menu item 314</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Menu item 32</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu item 33</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu item 34</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Menu item 4</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

I change a few styles to make it work, no rocketsince involved :)

Check out the fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/GLORIEN/gWFeW/](http://jsfiddle.net/GLORIEN/gWFeW/)

I changed the main list-element from inline-block to block, removed the float:left and added position: relative:

```
.vertical-nav li {
    height: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background-color: #666;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;  /******* MODIFIED ********/
}
```

Removed the display: table-row:

```
.sub-menu li {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 180px;
    white-space: nowrap;  
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
}
```

The list sub-navigation becomes the position: absolute and top: 0 and left: 100%:

```
.vertical-nav li ul {
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
```

There a more changes in the fiddle but they not importend to what you want.

-Sven

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add

```
clear:both;
```

to your `.vertical-nav li` style. This will make it vertical.

I also moved your submenu to the correct position. For this I have added

```
top: -37px;
left: -20px;
```

to your `.sub-menu li` style

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QdDmL/3/

Comment: In your fiddle, Menu doesn't slide to the right. It's incomplete answer.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QdDmL/2/ i have made the changes to make the sub menu display right but its not displaying in the correct place , any ideas?

Comment: Its coming from here `.sub-menu li` make it `margin-left:100px;`

Comment: This is because the parent list item is a block, and is taking up the whole width. If we could somehow have it be inline...

Comment: Although I upvoted this, it is kind of a hack, and it'd be nice to have a proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bp48q/)

```
nav ul li {
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    background: #aaa;
}
```

Comment: This answer does not use his existing code. Also just posting code with no explanation around it is what makes a low-quality answer

Answer (score 1):

This is my version of it [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QdDmL/4/)

This is what I've added:

```
.sub-menu{/* added */
   position:absolute;
    right:-95px;/* dependent on button size of main nav */
    top:0;
}
```

Further more I removed the `float:left;` and the `display:inline-block;` on the `li` as you can see in commented code on the fiddle.